# How to get the number of pages in Google Docs via Google script?

Tags: google-apps-script, google-docs

What should I do to get amount of pages in Google Docs (when converted to PDF) via Google script?

I have tried this, but it returns 0 instead of the number of pages.

```
function getNumPages() 
{
  var blob = DocumentApp.getActiveDocument().getAs("application/pdf");
   var data = blob.getDataAsString();
   var re = /Pages\/Count (\d+)/g;
   var match;
   var pages = 0;

   while(match = re.exec(data)) {
      Logger.log("MATCH = " + match[1]);

      var value = parseInt(match[1]);

      if (value > pages) {
         pages = value;
      }
   }

   Logger.log("pages = " + pages);

   return pages; 

}
```

Comment: What do you mean "it doesn't work"? Does it return an error, the wrong value or nothing at all?

Comment: Oh sorry, I mean it return 0 instead amount of pages.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Your regular expression expects a string like `Pages/Count 3` in the PDF file. Logging the contents of the file with `Logger.log(data)` shows there isn't such a string. Instead, I find the number of pages near the beginning of the file:

```
<< /Linearized 1 /L 18937 /H [ 687 137 ] /O 10 /E 17395 /N 3 /T 18641 >>
```

The number following /N is the number of pages. Here is a function extracting it:

```
function getNumPages() {
  var blob = DocumentApp.getActiveDocument().getAs("application/pdf");
  var data = blob.getDataAsString();
  var pages = parseInt(data.match(/ \/N (\d+) /)[1], 10);
  Logger.log("pages = " + pages);
  return pages; 
}
```

Comment: Why this need to be converted as PDF? @user3717023

Answer (score -1):

```
function getNumPages(docId) {
    var pages = 0;
    var blob = DocumentApp.openById(docId).getAs("application/pdf");
    var data = blob.getDataAsString();
    try {
        var matched = data.match(/\/Type[\s]*\/Page[^s]/g);
        pages = matched.length; 
    } catch(err) {
        // NOOP
    }
    return pages; 
}
```