# Is there any way to know if the same table is rendered into multiple pages in google doc?

Tags: google-docs, google-docs-api

When I render a table on a google doc, and if the table contains large content such that it makes the table to render on multiple pages.

**Is there a way to know if the same table is extended to multiple pages?
Using API or DOM or any other idea?**

Please check the below screenshot for the use case.

[image: Check the below Image for the scenario I am talking about]

Answer (score 0):

After looking at this there seems to not be a way to get the page of an element.
Neither with [Apps Script](https://developers.google.com/apps-script) nor the [Docs API](https://developers.google.com/docs/api).

The elements in both are placed by the [`startIndex` and `endIndex`](https://developers.google.com/docs/api/concepts/structure#start_and_end_index). My guess is that they do it this way because the index are more constant and will not depend on font/spacing used.

If you need to control when a new page starts there is actual an element called [PageBreak](https://developers.google.com/apps-script/reference/document/page-break) that my be useful for your case.

---

And if you think something like this should be implemented you can try look reporting a [new Feature Request for Apps Script](https://developers.google.com/apps-script/support#missing_features) or directly to the [Docs API](https://developers.google.com/docs/api/support#missing_features)

#### Useful Questions

- [How to get the number of pages in Google Docs via Google script?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/36432487/how-to-get-the-number-of-pages-in-google-docs-via-google-script)
- [How can I generate a multipage text document from a single page template in google-apps-script?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10692669/how-can-i-generate-a-multipage-text-document-from-a-single-page-template-in-goog)